# C# calculation different than excel

Tags: c#, math, calculator, calculation

If I run this simple calculation in C# the value is completely different than Excel or Win calculator.

```
var result = (300 / 250 * 4.3M * 25);
```

In c# the result is `107.5`

In Excel and Windows Calculator the result is `129`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `300 / 250` is integer division and would produce 1 in c#.

Comment: Damn! Good point!

Answer (score 1):

When you divide 300 with 250 - you divide 2 *integers* - so the results is 1 and not what you may expected - 1.2

When you do that in calculator the values are floating numbers and the results is 1.2 as expected

129 / 107 = 1.2